# What reasons do I have to believe that ~p->~q and pV~q are equivalent?

Tags: logic

I understand the reasoning for why pVq implies ~p->q, but not the converse. What reasons are there to believe ~p->~q implies pV~q, other than to make the whole material implication system neat?

Comment: TRUTH TABLE....

Comment: There isn't anyway to immediately or easily use a truth table without first presupposing this equivalence and the material implication.

Comment: The inference rule Material Implication is specifically defined as a conditional is equivalent to a disjunction with a denied or negative antecedent.  That is whatever the antecedent is in the conditional premise then we simply reverse the sign from positive to negative  or negative to positive AND replace the arrow symbol with a wedge. Another way to say this is find the antecedent, write it as a contradiction of the antecedent & use the wedge symbol. You can't get any more mechanical than this.

Comment: So let's say the original conditional statement is if s then p. The antecedent here is S.  We write down the contradictory of s which is NOT S and we simply change the logical connector to a wedge logical connector.  A truth table will verify that the truth table values will be identical.  There are no assumptions needed or used to prove this is the case.

Comment: There is no way for the truth table to prove this equivalence exists without presupposing the equivalence exists, i.e. without first assuming (p->q) <-> (~pVq). Just assuming that's what implications are equivalent to, and then subsequently using that assumption to work out that this assumption is true, is circular, invalid, and fallacious reasoning, which you shouldn't make a habit of.

Comment: It is just to make material implication neat. There was a great controversy among Stoic and some Medievial logicians about whether implication can be defined truth-functionally. In mathematical logic, we use material implication because it has nice mathematical properties. There's not really much other justification.

Comment: *There is no way for the truth table to prove this equivalence exists without presupposing the equivalence exists, i.e. without first assuming (p->q) <-> (~pVq)* The truth table for p->q doesn't refer to the statement ~pVq, are you just saying the truth table can be shown to logically imply ~pVq? Of course that's true, but in that case would you consider all logical deductions to be "circular reasoning"? Or do you have some prior intuition of the notion of what it means for one fact to "imply" another, and are you asking why logicians use that particular truth table to formalize the intuition?

Answer (score 1):

"If not p, then not q" means that we cannot have not p without having also not q.

Thus:

> either p or not p.

If p, then p or not q.

And if not p, then we must have not q (by premise above), and thus also p or not q.

---

As per other similar questions, the issue about the equivalence amounts to the "unpleasant" semantical definition of the classical connectives through truth tables.

The equivalence is "built-in" into the definition of the *conditional*: it is False exactly when p is True and q is False, and this is the only case when "not p or q" is False.

There are "alternative" to the classical (i.e. non truth-functional) definition of the *conditional* connective: see e.g. [Indicative Conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/), [Counterfactuals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/counterfactuals/), [Strict conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_conditional).

Comment: That's the question: why would p or not q follow?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use " sheffer stroke", that is, the operator : |

The proposition " X | Y" means : " not both X and Y", " X and Y are incompatible".

Let's define the conditional in terms of Sheffer's stroke :

"X --> Y" means : X | ~Y . ( In words : not both X and not Y)

Let's also define disjunction

"  X v Y " means ~X | ~Y  ( Not both ~X and ~Y).

Now in the the sheffer's stroke language, what does " ~ p --> q " mean.

Here, ~ p plays the role of X, and q plays the role of Y.

So " ~ p --> q " is : ~p | ~q. ( In words : ~ p and ~ q are incompatible).

Now, let p play the role of X and q play the role of Y.

As we said above : "~X | ~Y" means "X OR Y".

So : "~p | ~q " means : " p OR q".

Conclusion : ***(~ p --> q)  means (~ p | ~ q) which in turn means  (p v q) .***

Comment: Claiming x or y means some 3rd thing and claiming that 3rd thing means ~x->y and that x or y therefore means ~x->y is thanks.

Comment: @Hicarra.-You may accept the answer in case you consider it adresses the qiuestion

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the more intuitively satisfying consequences of material conditional. I'' put the reasoning in English, since that's all that can be added to other answers.

"If I don't go to the store, I won't have milk" = ¬P->¬Q

So by assumption, I neither go to the store, nor do i have milk. Ie, ¬P is true, and ¬Q is true.

"One of these are true: i go to the store, or I don't have milk" = Pv¬Q

By ¬P->¬Q, i don;t go to the store, nor do i have milk. Pv¬Q is true if just one of these are true: I go to the store, or i don't have milk.

We know I don't have milk: ¬Q. But if ¬Q, then Pv¬Q.

So essentially, by ¬Pv¬Q, we know that both of ¬P and ¬Q are false.

By Pv¬Q, we know that one of ¬P or ¬Q are false. So, Pv¬Q is made true by the fact that ¬P->¬Q makes both ¬P and ¬Q true.

What make be tripping you up is the though that Pv¬Q seems to allow P to be true, which contradicts ¬P->¬Q. But Pv¬Q only says that ONE of P and ¬Q are true. If BOTH are true, which they are, then one is true. Pv¬Q is indifferent about whether both are true or if one is true: it's true on either option.

Answer (score 0):

These are not equivalent, [constructively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)), unless your domain is finite and discrete.

In finite terms, any false statement has a finite list of test cases where it fails, which we will call a counterexample.  That is the only way for it to be false.  So if p and q are both about well-defined, finite things, this equivalence is true.  (That is why we freely use it as a definition in computing and other applications to the real world.)

In such a case, if I have a proof of 'not q' from 'not p' then I always have a counterexample to q, derived from the fact p has a counterexample.  That can be true only if I can compute some counterexample to q from any counterexample to p.

If p is true, then 'p or not q' is true, by definition of 'or'.  If p is false, (and it is about well-defined, finite things) then it has a counterexample.  And, given the reasoning above, from that counterexample, I can compute a counterexample to q.

But if p is not about finite things, or it is not well-defined, then it can be false without presenting a counterexample.  "These two lines cross" can be false, but since they are infinite objects, we cannot give a constructive proof they are false by looking at all the places they might cross and finding none. The reasoning above does not apply anymore, the input to our conversion from counterexamples of p to counterexamples of q can't get its input.

In the finite case, all the details can be enclosed in the accounting of the falsehood, and the proof can still be finite in length.  That is not true in the infinite case.  You have to look inside p and q for details that will allow the negative case to be expressed in a finite way.  And you may or may not be able to do that.

So if you want proof to mean a finite chain of implications leading from one place to another, then generalizing over all p's and q's in this way does not leave a convincing way of getting a proof here.

We do know that it is *safe* to paper over this with assumptions like that a falsehood implies anything and that any truth implies any other truth, and that the world is neatly divided into true and false statements.  But we know that a proof that "dogs are brown implies elephants are grey" is not a logical deduction in any normal sense.  It is just a safe one, that won't cause any new contradictions.

Likewise, we do not know that every statement is either true or false, in an open-ended domain.  Statements can be undecidable.  But we trust that even if they are undecidable they are not sometimes true and other times false.  So a little arrogance here cannot get us into trouble.  It remains arrogance, not truth.  Even that idea that they maintain the same undefined truth value could fail.

Every proof you can get of this fact is going to draw on one of these three 'conventionally true' axioms that don't act like real proofs, or that assume omniscience of some sort.  And that may be the intuition that is getting in your way.

It is quicker to suspend it, and accept the traditional set of shortcuts that generalize from finite cases in ways that remain safe.  (But it is not honest, and it does not produce proofs with the same level of applicability to real situations.)